# Swift 4 SwiftyJSON: Appending JSON results as Strings to an array

Tags: arrays, json, swift4, xcode9

I am having issues with appending JSON results onto an empty array using SwiftyJSON. In the view controller, I have the following:

```
var jsonResults = [String]()

func runAPI() {
    let jsonUrlString = "sampleUrl"
    guard let url = URL(string: jsonUrlString) else {
        return
    }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data else {
            return
        }

        do {
            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)

            self.jsonResults.append(JSON(json).stringValue) // SwiftyJSON used here
            print(JSON(json)) // prints a string on the console
            print(JSON(json).stringValue) // prints the same string on the console
        } catch let jsonError {
            print("Error serializing json:", jsonError)
        }
    }
    .resume()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    runAPI()
    print(jsonResults.count) // prints "0" :(
}
```

I was hoping if someone had any ideas on how to get a JSON result converted into a string and appended onto an array. Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `print` line in `viewDidLoad` displays always 0 because `dataTask` works asynchronously. *how to get a JSON result converted into a string* cannot be answered without knowing the JSON data.

Comment: Thanks vadian. I read about dataTask and realized its asynchronous process. Adding in DispatchQueue.main.async with the print(jsonResults.count), after the do-catch statement, provides the count I am looking for. Thanks for the tip.